# OpenGl : Finding out your current position

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, matrix

Right imagine your at 0,1,0 or even a cube is.  You then rotate 45% (glRotatef), then you move that object forward (glTranslate 0,0,10) so you move that object 10 forward.

How do you then get that objects position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the transformations into one matrix, and then apply this to any point to give you its world position.  You can do this by querying the current matrix (after applying all your rotations, translations and scalings) and using this to apply transforms to arbitrary points.

Note that by using `glRotatef` and glTranslatef`, you are using immediate mode and the old-style APIs.  Modern OpenGL usage would have you create matrices and send them to shaders to apply the transforms from object to world coordinates.  In this way, you would already have the matrix for object-to-world transforms.

Comment: You can use: `float modelViewMatrix[16]; glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMatrix);` to query the current transform.  Then you can apply this matrix to any point in model space to get world coordinates.

Comment: If you could just help me with the next step.  how do I apply it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you'd want to use the `gluProject` function from GLu library (comes with OpenGL).

Comment: My project has it but I am not sure why I need it

Comment: It could do some work for you. In fact, you don't really *need* to use it - it would be certainly enough in your specific case to call `glGetDoublev` with `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` as an argument and multiply your position by this matrix.

Comment: How do I actually do that I got the matrix and looked at it but how do i then multiply it by my position?

Comment: Implement this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication . I'm also positive that there's a  `boost` library which can do this... Oh, wait, you're on iPhone and ObjC - so no boost :)

Comment: OpenGL's not really complex. It just expects one to know some basic mathematics concepts like vector/matrix algebra + some general theory on 3D graphics rendering. After all, it's a low-level API, not a game engine or anything.

Comment: True, I am hoping someone will make a 3D picking example for the iphone but with a movable camera